# How to specify the name and location of the output file when using nbconvert?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

When using `nbconvert`, how can I specify the name and directory of the new file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--output` flag to change the name of the converted file

Use the `--output-dir` flag to change the directory of the converted file

```
jupyter nbconvert <path/to/notebook.ipynb>  --to <x> --output <"name" (without file extension)> --output-dir <path/to/new/file>
```